# In open source development, what is the difference between a patch and a git commit?

Tags: linux, git, open-source, patch

As far as I know, a patch is a file describing the differences between some files. It seem like a neat way to communicate changes in source code.

But a git commit does that, and so much more. Why send patch files over the email when you could do pull requests (with all the associated metainformation, git mechanisms, and automation)?

Essentially, why/when is one used over the other?

Comment: A pull request is a GitHub concept, not a Git one.

Comment: @Jubobs Yes I'm aware of that but it gets the point across. Other systems like BitBucket use it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.

Let’s just assume that everyone is using Git. Then why ever use patches?

Some downsides of using commits:

- You have to have a public repository somewhere in order to communicate
  with people

  - With `git format-patch` and `git send-email` you just need to have
    an email provider configured to send emails on your behalf
- Email is a sort of lowest-common demoninatorb

  - This is debatable!—having to set up your email send-out for
    patch-based workflows (where the patches are embedded in the email)
    can be difficult, and even some very experienced developers (who
    have used this style of development for years or decades) thinks
    it’s antiquated
  - This means that tooling around patches needs to understand a
    well-established email format, compared to learning the APIs of all
    of the different Git forges
- If you email patches to a public mailing list, you can gather the
  discussion around the patches on that email thread; you can discuss
  individual lines and hunks of code directly in the email

  - You could use Git forges together with email, but then you might
    have to constantly say things like “see commit  on my GitHub”,
    “see commit  on my GitLab”; everyone might have different
    forges that they just link to instead of discussing the code
    directly in the email

#### Agility

If you’re—skilled—I can’t comment personally on this point—, you can go
from having a regular conversation to proposing changes immediately. For
example: [1]

```
> So we should do such-and-such.

Makes sense to me.  How about this patch?

-- >8 --
Subject: [IA64] Put ia64 config files on the Uwe Kleine-König diet

arch/arm config files were slimmed down using a python script
```

#### Notes

1. Taken from `man git format-patch`

Answer (score 1):

One reason is that a patch is generic mechanism and is supported in every version control system (svn, cvs etc.). You can create patches of any changes in your file system, not even being under version control! Pull requests, on the other hand, are quite handy, but this is github (bitbucket etc.) specific mechanism, so it's less generic.

I think also some projects use patches because of historical reasons/habits.